# dynamic table base on database field

Tags: php, codeigniter

Help me, i got stack when i want to make a dynamic table,

so the idea of the program is we can be costume a select field of database and can show it.
 so if we have this field on table in database :

1. No
2. Name
3. age
4. Address

   and we just want to show Name and Address, so i save the rule on the database (SELECT Name, Address)

   but the problem is on the dynamic table when i show, how to make dynamic table when field always change (Example :Maybe the field just Age, or Name and age or we show all #its just from Configure that i make)

i have tried to make query result into an array and show it like this.

```
<table>
    <?php for($x=0;$x<$length_array;$x++){ ?>
        <tr>
            <?php for($y=0;$y<$width_array;$y++){ ?>
                <td><?php $result[$length_array][$width_array] ?></td>
            <?php } ?>  
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

note : variable $result is from result query and i change it into an array, but the problem is i cann't count a length and width from array in this code.

Comment: Can you please not use blockquotes? Edit: thank you.

Comment: Is this related to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53474470/1415724) ?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner done

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes it is, but i still cann't find an answer.

Comment: the answer given on your previous question is the way to solve your problem.

Comment: @Jhecht on my previous question the answer just show the field, i mean i want to show the record of the field too.

Comment: what do you mean by "record of the field"?

Comment: @Jhecht i mean the data, so it's not just show a column name but also show the data.

Comment: get the first row, loop through the columns there. Big hint, it would be `foreach($firstRow as $key=>$value){ echo "<th>".$key."</th>"; }` for the first row

Comment: `print_r()` the result array so we can get an idea of its structure. i have a pretty good idea, but want to make sure before making a recommendation. further please include the *relevant* controller/model code blocks **in the question**

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on how your result set is returned, but based on your code above I'll assume your result is an array of arrays.

First think about what you want: you want an html table with a header that gives the name for each column, and then has a row for each record in your result set.

I very much dislike mixing php and html, so I will use a different syntax style, but the steps are the same no matter what style you use. This way makes the logic a lot easer to read.

First, make the table.

```
<?php
$html = '<table>';
```

Now you want to add a header to the table and create a cell for each column in your result. Before you do that, you need to answer: where are you going to get the names for you columns? There are two possible answers; 1) directly from the results of your query, or 2) hard-code them.

Getting them directly from the query results is much more flexible, but the names you give your database columns may not always be human-friendly.

```
$columnNames = ['Name', 'Address'];
```

---- OR ----

```
$firstRow = $result[0]; // of course we have checked that the result set is not empty!
$columnNames = array_keys($firstRow); // adjust if rows are objects instead of arrays
```

Now output the header:

```
$html .= '<thead>';
foreach($columnNames as $columnName) {
    $html .= '<th>' . $columnName . '</th>';
}
$html .= '</thead>';
```

Now we can move on to the body, as in the answer to your previous question, creating a row in the table for each item in your result set. For each row you have an inner loop that creates the markup for each cell.

```
$html .= '<tbody>';

foreach($result as $row) {
    $html .= '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $cell) {
        $html .= '<td>' . $cell . '</td>';
    }
    $html .= '</tr>';
}

$html .= '</tbody>';
$html .= '</table>';

print $html;
```